# woocommerce search bar custom fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have a event ticket booking site where i am using Woocommerce, can anyone help me to put a custom search bar on homepage with custom search fields like 'Location', 'Date', 'Event Name' ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you told us what plugin you're using for the ticketing. Woocommerce by itself doesn't do tickets.

Comment: I am using 'YITH WooCommerce Event Tickets" plugin.